# Spring JMS: How work with `ActiveMQ Advisory Message`

Tags: jms, activemq-classic, spring-jms, jms-topic

For a `Spring Framework` app working with `ActiveMQ` and with/without `WebSocket`

The requirement is prior to send any message to a `Topic` a check should be done about `Number Of Consumers`, if it returns 1 the message can be sent safely. If it returns 0, the message can't be sent.

The clients could be come from websocket and consider there is no durable subscription. Thus if a message is sent, and there are no clients, the message arrives to the `Topic` and practically is lost (never consumed) and `Messages Enqueued` increments +1

I already did a research and I have read the following:

- [JMSTemplate check if topic exists and get subscriber count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44707064/jmstemplate-check-if-topic-exists-and-get-subscriber-count)
- [Notify ActiveMQ producer if consumer on the destination is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340546/notify-activemq-producer-if-consumer-on-the-destination-is-down)
- [ActiveMQ get number of consumers listening to a topic from java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10291452/activemq-get-number-of-consumers-listening-to-a-topic-from-java)
- [Detect change in Consumers of an ActiveMQ topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43319224/detect-change-in-consumers-of-an-activemq-topic)

Practically all is based on `Advisory Message`. I already have read:

- [Advisory Message](http://activemq.apache.org/advisory-message.html)
- [Handling Advisory Messages](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/handling-advisory-messages.html)
- [Apache ActiveMQ Advisory Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jms/apache-activemq-advisory-example/)

I understand that if exists a `Topic` named `abc.xyz` then `ActiveMQ` creates `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.abc.xyz`, until here I am ok with this pattern. I can confirm this approach through `ActiveMQ Web Console`

What is confuse for me is that practically all the examples available from the previous links works around creating a `Session` and uses mostly the `onMessage` method. For the latter I know it works how a listener.

**Question 01**: Thus who is expected to call that `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.abc.xyz`? It to trigger that `onMessage` method? That is my confusion.

What I need is work with the `Spring Framework` API (The app is already working and running with a `CachingConnectionFactory`, thus a `Connection` can be retrieved and other `@Beans` about infrastructure about `ActiveMQ`) **and** get access to that `ActiveMQ.Advisory.Consumer.Topic.abc.xyz` destination and retrieve the `Number Of Consumers` value.

**Note**: even when exists `ActiveMQTopic` declared with `@Bean` and is possible to retrieve that `Destination` for some `@Component`, sadly the API does not offer a method such `getConsumers()`.

**Question 02:** How can be accomplished this?

I am assuming the `JMS` API for 2.0.x could help perhaps in someway.